# How to make an mp3 file from another site downloadable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, audio, download

I almost feel ashamed to ask such a basic question, what with how i like to term my self a website genius when with friends this seems quite basic.

I'm trying to get visitors to my site to download an mp3 link=> "http://www.podbean.com/podcast-directory-download-public/4995714/10_Commandments_Of_A_Successful_Home_Pst_Abiodun_Koloewo.mp3". But the problem i'm facing is that it won't download unless one right clicks and selects "save link as" and i can't do anything about it since the file's not on my server. any help here?

Answer (score 1):

You have two methods, one of which only works in Chrome.

### Use the [download](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a#Attributes) attribute:

<sub>Though this is used in Firefox, it states:`In Firefox 20 this attribute is only honored for links to resources with the same-origin.` so it doesn't work.</sub>

Example:

```
<a href="http://www.podbean.com/podcast-directory-download-public/4995714/10_Commandments_Of_A_Successful_Home_Pst_Abiodun_Koloewo.mp3" download>Download Song</a>
```

### Use your server as a proxy:

Example:

```
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: Binary"); 
header("Content-disposition: attachment;filename=\"10_Commandments_Of_A_Successful_Home_Pst_Abiodun_Koloewo.mp3\"");
readfile("http://www.podbean.com/podcast-directory-download-public/4995714/10_Commandments_Of_A_Successful_Home_Pst_Abiodun_Koloewo.mp3");
```

For this example to work, please enable [`allow_url_fopen`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.allow-url-fopen).

In addition to this, I would recommend saving the song file on your server, so that new requests for this song can just be downloaded from your server again.